# How to get two media stream from one File (for Custom Mixer)

Tags: ms-media-foundation, mixer

There is one file with two video stream.

1. I want to mix these two stream to make one output stream.(using media session)
2. I think we can write the topology as shown below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701605(v=vs.85).aspx

```
IMFActivate         *pSinkActivate = NULL;
IMFTopologyNode     *pOutputNode = NULL;

pPD->GetStreamDescriptorCount(&cSourceStreams);
// For each stream, create the topology nodes and add them to the topology.
for (DWORD i = 0; i < cSourceStreams; i++)
{
    IMFStreamDescriptor *pSD = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode     *pSourceNode = NULL;

    pPD->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(i, &fSelected, &pSD);
    // Create the media sink activation object.
    if (i == 0)
        CreateMediaSinkActivate(pSD, hVideoWnd, &pSinkActivate);
    // Add a source node for this stream.
    AddSourceNode(pTopology, pSource, pPD, pSD, &pSourceNode);
    // Create the output node for the renderer.
    if (i == 0)
        AddOutputNode(pTopology, pSinkActivate, 0, &pOutputNode);

    // Connect the source node to the output node.
    pSourceNode->ConnectOutput(0, pOutputNode, 0);

    SafeRelease(&pSD);
    SafeRelease(&pSourceNode);
}
SafeRelease(&pSinkActivate);
SafeRelease(&pOutputNode);
```

I don't know if I'm doing well.

please help me.

thanks.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You have to add two different source nodes for each  stream. You also have to create two different sinks if that's your intention. You cannot instantiate the same pSinkActivate and the same pSourceNode twice. You have to manually connect each source node to each sink, or if you have a single sink - to each input stream node of the sink.

Comment: @VuVirt sorry
I made the wrong sample.
I have rewritten the sample in detail, so please review it again.

Comment: still wrong. You need a separate outputNode for each stream of the renderer media sink.

Comment: @VuVirt Can i mixing the two streams by creating media sink and outputnode for each of the two streams?

Comment: It should be possible, but you have to take into consideration several limitations and requirements, like secondary stream input media types. I think you should better implement a custom MFT mixer as well. You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb970394(v=vs.85).aspx and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701624(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @VuVirt Is it right to add both media sink and output node to both streams?  I'll try. thank you for helping me.

Comment: Only 1 media sink.
1 output node for each input stream.